# how to uninstall truffle in usr/bin

Tags: truffle

My truffle got installed in usr/bin/truffle, how do I uninstall it,

```
npm uninstall/remove
```

is not working, please help.

Thanks

Comment: using sudo npm uninstall -g truffle     i was able to uninstall, I did that earlier but i don't know why it didn't happened , but this time is was successful

Comment: it doesn't work so stop upvote yourself

Answer (score 4):

I was unable to uninstall using `npm uninstall -g` so this is what I had to do:

```
$ which truffle
/usr/local/bin/truffle

$ rm -f /usr/local/bin/truffle
```

Now I can reinstall the latest truffle if needed:

```
$ npm i -g truffle@5.0.0-beta.2
/Users/mota/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/truffle -> /Users/mota/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
+ truffle@5.0.0-beta.2
updated 1 package in 3.081s

$ which truffle
/Users/mota/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/truffle
```

Answer (score 2):

"sudo npm uninstall -g truffle".It worked for me.